# Stopwatch for command prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash

Is there a stopwatch, so that I can measure time taken for different commands for BASH shell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`time [command]` returns the time taken for the command to complete.

```
steven@wind:~$ time du /storage -s
du: cannot read directory `/storage/lost+found': Permission denied
1548584024      /storage

real    0m4.046s
user    0m0.224s
sys     0m1.496s
steven@wind:~$ time sleep 5

real    0m5.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
steven@wind:~$
```

Comment: Might be worth adding that (in bash,) time's output can be modified with the TIMEFORMAT variable. E.g. with the last example, `TIMEFORMAT=%R; time sleep 5` would output just the real time in seconds; `5.003`. And if you want to capture time's output, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032 explains how.